# Concatenating long XML strings with imports

Tags: python

In building unit tests I wish to create a long configuration XML test.  In various packages (18 so far) I have a number of test modules.
For those modules that test the reading and writing of the XML for a given package I have the XML sub-tree that is used for that package.  Each sub-tree is contained in a triple quoted string.

I am trying to build a master XML testing module and I have not been able to get a single triple quoted XML string that I can use.

in package internet_xml I have:

```
INTERNET_XML = """
    <InternetSection>
        <LocaterUrlSection>
            <LocateUrl>http://elsewhere.com/ip/</LocateUrl>
            <LocateUrl>http://checkip.dyndns.com/</LocateUrl>
        </LocaterUrlSection>
        <UpdaterUrlSection>
            <UpdateUrl>http://freedns.somewhere.com/dynamic/update.php?abc</UpdateUrl>
        </UpdaterUrlSection>
        <ExternalIPv4>65.35.48.61</ExternalIPv4>
        <ExternalIPv6>1234:5678::1</ExternalIPv6>
        <LastChanged>2014-10-02 12:34:56</LastChanged>
    </InternetSection>
"""
```

In another module testing a larger portion of the daemon I am trying to build a more complete XML document by importing a bunch of pieces from other modules.

```
from Modules.Computer.Internet.test.test_internet_xml import INTERNET_XML

LONG_XML = """\
<Pyhouse Version='2'>
"""
INTERNET_XML
WEB_SERVER_XML
XXX_MODULE_XML
"""
</PyHouse>
"""
```

How do I build up this long string that I can parse and use for testing?

I have tried parens, backslashes, pluses, and anything else I can think of and can not get it to work.

Comment: `'\n'.join([LONG_XML, INTERNET_XML, ETC_XML])`?

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.  I never needed join before so I have learned something new.